# In the output I am not getting the complete table from Excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I just started using pandas, i wanted to import one Excel file with 31 rows and 11 columns, but in the output only some columns are displayed, the middle columns are represented by "....", and the first column 'EST' the starting few elements are displayed "00:00:00".

## Code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\daryl\PycharmProjects\pandas\Book1.xlsx")

print(df)
```

## Output

```
C:\Users\daryl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe "C:/Users/daryl/PycharmProjects/pandas/1. Introduction.py"
                    EST  Temperature  ...    Events  WindDirDegrees
0   2016-01-01 00:00:00           38  ...       NaN             281
1   2016-02-01 00:00:00           36  ...       NaN             275
2   2016-03-01 00:00:00           40  ...       NaN             277
3   2016-04-01 00:00:00           25  ...       NaN             345
4   2016-05-01 00:00:00           20  ...       NaN             333
5   2016-06-01 00:00:00           33  ...       NaN             259
6   2016-07-01 00:00:00           39  ...       NaN             293
7   2016-08-01 00:00:00           39  ...       NaN              79
8   2016-09-01 00:00:00           44  ...      Rain              76
9   2016-10-01 00:00:00           50  ...      Rain             109
10  2016-11-01 00:00:00           33  ...       NaN             289
11  2016-12-01 00:00:00           35  ...       NaN             235
12            1-13-2016           26  ...       NaN             284
13            1-14-2016           30  ...       NaN             266
14            1-15-2016           43  ...       NaN             101
15            1-16-2016           47  ...      Rain             340
16            1-17-2016           36  ...  Fog-Snow             345
17            1-18-2016           25  ...      Snow             293
18            1/19/2016           22  ...       NaN             293
19            1-20-2016           32  ...       NaN             302
20            1-21-2016           31  ...       NaN             312
21            1-22-2016           26  ...      Snow              34
22            1-23-2016           26  ...  Fog-Snow              42
23            1-24-2016           28  ...      Snow             327
24            1-25-2016           34  ...       NaN             286
25            1-26-2016           43  ...       NaN             244
26            1-27-2016           41  ...      Rain             311
27            1-28-2016           37  ...       NaN             234
28            1-29-2016           36  ...       NaN             298
29            1-30-2016           34  ...       NaN             257
30            1-31-2016           46  ...       NaN             241

[31 rows x 11 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

### To answer your question about the display of only a few columns and "..." :

All of the columns have been properly ingested, but your screen / the console is not wide enough to output all of the columns at once in a "print" fashion. This is normal/expected behavior.

Pandas is not a spreadsheet visualization tool like Excel. Maybe someone can suggest a tool for visualizing dataframes in a spreadsheet format for Python, like in Excel. I think I've seen people visualizing spreadsheets in [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) but I don't use that myself.

If you want to make sure all of the columns are there, try using `list(df)` or `print(list(df))`.

### To answer your question about the EST format:

It looks like you have some data cleaning to do. This is typical work in data science. I am not sure how to best do this - I haven't worked much with dates/datetime yet. However, here is what I see:

- The first few items have timestamps as well, likely formatted in HH:MM:SS
- They are formatted YYYY-MM-DD
- On index row 18, there are / instead of - in the date
- The remaining rows are formatted M-DD-YYYY

There's an option on [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)'s documentation that may take care of those automatically. It's called "`parse_dates`". If you turn that option on like `pd.read_csv('file location', parse_dates='EST')`, that could turn on the date parser for the EST column and maybe solve your problem.

Hope this helps! This is my first answer to anyone who sees it feel free to edit and improve it.